# How to convert firebase timestamp into date and time as Date is deprecated

Tags: android, firebase

How do i convert ServerValue.TIMESTAMP into SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy")
Date is deprecated so not able to use it , is their is any way to use calender

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `Server.TIMESTAMP` to get a date. The doc says:

> A placeholder value for auto-populating the current timestamp (time since the Unix epoch, in milliseconds) as determined by the Firebase servers

This means that when you `setValue()` or `updateChildren()`, you can put this constant in the `Map` to tell the server to put the epoch time in that node instead. For example:

```
mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().child("whatever/path/in/your/database");
mRef.setValue( Server.TIMESTAMP );
```

This will set in `<your Firebase>/whatever/path/in/your/database` a long that will look like 149141530600. This is the current epoch time I fetched while writing this answer. It corresponds to the number of milliseconds passed since january 1st 1970 to when I copied the value. Then, if you have a listener to that node, you can get the calendar using:

```
Long time = dataSnapshot.getValue(Long.class);
Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(time);
```

If you only want the time the server is set to (saving it in the database is pointless), you can use the special node:

```
`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/serverTimeOffset");`
```

A listener to this node returns a `Double` that represents an approximative offset between the device time and the server time. You can then set the `Calendar` using:

`calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis() + offset);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

cal.setTimeInMillis(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy",Locale.US);
fmt.format(cal.getTime()); //This returns a string formatted in the above way.
```

If ServerValue.TIMESTAMP is returned as a string, you can parse the string using `Long.parseLong(Server.TIMESTAMP);`

Comment: ServerValue.TIMESTAMP is map<String , String> type so its not working

Comment: Nops it will not work , u can not convert map type directly to Long like this