# How do I convert firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP to its corresponding date or time now?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my code, where I push a newsObj to the realtime database

```
   addNewsObj(newsObj:News) {
    this.newsListRef.push(newsObj).then((snap) => {
      const key = snap.key;
      console.log(key);
      this.newsListRef.update(key, {news_timestamp_post_created: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP});
    });
   }
```

The outcome I want would be converting the long value I get from the db, something like this

```
news_timestamp_post_created: 
1535716975480
```

To 59 mins ago or when it exceeds 24hrs, it displays it by days then months as time goes on. I wouldn't want something like 3000mins ago or 120days ago to be displayed on my app.

My problem here is that I dont know how to convert this 1535716975480 to readable terms

Any small tip would be a great help. Thank you!

EDIT:

I have tried doing this

```
let elapsed = news.news_timestamp_post_created;//1535716975480 
console.log(new Date(elapsed));
```

which displayed 'Invalid date'

According to this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43237884/how-to-convert-firebase-timestamp-into-date-and-time-as-date-is-deprecated/43238638),  the server timestamp is

```
"The doc says:

A placeholder value for auto-populating the current timestamp (time since the Unix epoch, in milliseconds) as determined by the Firebase servers"
```

I found out that, [image: pic]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript timestamp to relative time (eg 2 seconds ago, one week ago etc), best methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108819/javascript-timestamp-to-relative-time-eg-2-seconds-ago-one-week-ago-etc-best)

Comment: Please read my updated question, thank you!

Comment: So basicly you want to convert the timestamp to date and time?

Comment: Yes, I tried putting it inside new Date(elapsed) but it says it is an invalid date

Comment: Please include you attempt inside your question (including the actual value of elapsed)